# Overlay add-on when scrolling image in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I have an image that is a map floor. I overlay areas using canvas and image overlays (canvas add-on and overlay add-on). However, when I scroll the map floor, the overlays stay where they were clicked, they don't move along with the scroll. Hence, when I scroll the image the overlays and canvas, they are positioned according to the browser (absolute position) instead of positioning according to the image (relative).

Answer (score 0):

there is only one solution for this: since the overlays add-on doesn't allow to change the position to relative instead of absolute, the browser itself needs to allow horizontal overflow.